# Make commit message appear as comment in bitbucket

Tags: github, bitbucket

Is there a way to make bitbucket show commit messages as part of comments/activity related to a specific issue, whenever it's been marked-up in said message; the same way github does?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Issues, pull requests, users and commit hashes can [be linked in BitBucket issues and commit messages](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Mark+up+comments,+issues,+and+commit+messages).

Issues [can be closed automatically by including something like `resolves #123`](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Resolve+issues+automatically+when+users+push+code). Commits referencing `issue 123` will generate a cross-reference in the issue. This relies on the [issues hook](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+the+Issues+hook) to be enabled, which is done by default on new (after August, 2012) issues-enabled repositories.

Answer (score 2):

A little more specific to this, as I had the issue where I was putting issues into my commits, ala "issue #89" which gave me links from the commit into the issue, but not vice versa. Finally found that only a specific set of commands would cause the issue to cross-reference to the commit. This [issue](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/7416/reference-commits-into-issues-as-comments) led to this [guide of actions](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-the-issues-service-223216615.html):

so if I use "ref bug #89", then I got the links and cross referencing in the commit and issue i was looking for.