# How do I make BitBucket recognize line breaks in commit comments?

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket, commit, commit-message

I work with mercurial, and use long(ish), multi-line commit comments.

Recently, I've put my project on BitBucket.org, and have noticed that when my commit comments are appended to issue pages (see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21151792/1593077) for information on how/when that happens), the newlines are replaced with spaces, while double-newlines stay double-newlines.

How should I mark single-newlines in commit messages so that BitBucket acknowledges them? I'd like to do this in the least-obtrusive way for when I read the comments normally from the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break paragraphs (generating `<p>` tags) with a blank line. Break lines (generating a `<br>` tag) by ending the first line with two or more spaces, e.g.

```
Line one␣␣
Line two
```

Bitbucket formats comments using [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax), which has [this to say about paragraphs and line breaks](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#p):

> ### Paragraphs and Line Breaks
>
> A paragraph is simply one or more consecutive lines of text, separated by one or more blank lines. (A blank line is any line that looks like a blank line — a line containing nothing but spaces or tabs is considered blank.) Normal paragraphs should not be indented with spaces or tabs.
>
> The implication of the "one or more consecutive lines of text" rule is that Markdown supports "hard-wrapped" text paragraphs. This differs significantly from most other text-to-HTML formatters (including Movable Type’s "Convert Line Breaks" option) which translate every line break character in a paragraph into a `<br />` tag.
>
> When you do want to insert a `<br />` break tag using Markdown, you end a line with two or more spaces, then type return.
>
> Yes, this takes a tad more effort to create a `<br />`, but a simplistic "every line break is a `<br />`" rule wouldn’t work for Markdown. Markdown’s email-style blockquoting and multi-paragraph list items work best — and look better — when you format them with hard breaks.